# How do I populate a name value inside a Coldfusion CFOUTPUT

Tags: input, coldfusion, attributes, tags

This is an update from a previous question. I'm not sure if this is even possible but I have a CFOUTPUT tag that has a single input tag inside it. This input tag equates to 65 possible checkboxes. The problem I'm having is trying to figure out what value to put in the name attribute of the input tag. I need 22 unique names that are static and don't change. My code is as follows:

```
<form action="new_processOptInfo.cfm"  id="displayOptions" method="post" name="displayOptions">

<cfoutput query="categorize" group="categoryName">
<h3>#UCASE(categoryName)#</h3>

<cfoutput>
<input type="checkbox" value="#idOptions#" name="option1"  /> #option#<br>
</cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitOptions" id="submitOptions" />
</form>
```

So how do I name the input tag?

Comment: Why do they need to have unique names? If they all have the same name then the form variable on the action page will have a comma-delimited list of values in one variable.

Comment: It is possible there is an easier way to go about this. Can you elaborate on your ultimate goal in plain English? ie What is the problem you are trying to solve, not how you are attempting to solve it.

Comment: In plain English I want to have unique names for my checkboxes that are generated automatically. I thought that when you INSERT values into a table the form tag names have to be unique.

Comment: That is *how* you want to do it. I am asking *what* you are trying to do - overall. ie "I have form that displays a list of products. Users can select one more products they want to purchase. I then need to insert the selected product id's into table `x`, that has this structure ...". *form tag names have to be unique* No, field names are are not required to be unique. The naming convention used all depends on what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a form that allows someone to choose certain options for houses. When they hit submit these options get inserted into a table. I want to know how to get those values into the table without a unique name. I realized from @FishBelowtheIce that the info is coming to the action page as a list. I will edit my original post to show the new code I have.

Comment: FYI, S.O. uses a Q&A model (Question and Answer). If you overwrite the original "question" the subsequent comments or "answers" no longer make sense ;-) Solutions should be posted as an "answer" instead. Rolled back changes to preserve context.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to a comment OP made.

> In plain English I want to have unique names for my checkboxes that are generated automatically. I thought that when you INSERT values into a table the form tag names have to be unique

(This reply was just too many characters to leave as a comment.)

For the record, field names don't have to be unique. Cold Fusion receives duplicate field names' values in a comma delimited list. There's actually great use in that. You can have 50 checkbox named p_IDs and if 3 are checked cold fusion will recieve the values checked (like 7,15,32, if those were the values checked).

This is extremely useful with cfloops like

```
<cfloop list="#form.p_IDs#" index="p">Product #p# selected</cfloop>.
```

You can name corresponding input field, like textboxes like

```
<input name="desc_#dbID#" type="text">
<input type="checkbox" name="p_IDs" value="#dbID#">
```

And then in the cfloop on processing page use code like

```
<cfloop list="#form.p_IDs#" index="p">
  Product #p#'s description is #form["desc_#p#"]#
</cfloop>
```

You could place an insert query into the cfloop (or an update, or delete query).

Examples of where this is useable is say if you wanted to mass delete selected rows, rather than deleting each row individually.

This functionality (works in a similar fashion across nearly every language) is the beauty of checkboxes. You can name them different things, but why would you want to? As far as radio buttons, naming them different things defeats their purpose.

On the subject of other input elements though, certainly name them different things.

Answer (score 0):

As @FishBelowtheIce said option1 is being sent to the action page as a list so when I was made aware of that and looped through it. I just had to fix my typos and it worked. The code below is what I have now.

```
<cfif IsDefined("form.submitOptions")>
  <cfloop index="index" list="#options#" delimiters="," >
      <cfquery name="updateInsOpTable" datasource="applewood">
         INSERT INTO ins_opt_table
         ( address,option1,option2,option3,option4,option5,option6
          , option7,option8,option9,option10,option11,option12
          , option13,option14,option15,option16,option17,option18
         )
         VALUES (#form.address#, #options#)
      </cfquery>
  </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Do you have control over the db design? Because that is really not a great table structure... Column names like `prop1,prop2,..propN` are almost always a sign to normalize. A better approach is storing the selected options in rows, not columns. Then both selecting and inserting values are simple. Also, never use raw form values in SQL like this `VALUES (#form.address#, #options#)`. It exposes your db to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Always use [cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html)

Comment: That is asking for trouble, how it is decided what is selected and what is the order of selection? As @Leigh said, you need to normalize DB design. If you do not have control over that, then you will be better doing with giving each checkbox a different name, like say `option#opt#` where opt is incremental variable starting at 1 and then in your action page you can check whether the option is present (it won't be if not selected) specify a default value if not.

Comment: Another problem with this answer is that it will throw an error if the user does not check a box for every option.   For what you are attempting, radio buttons are a better option than checkboxes.